# Dynamic htaccess redirects in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am looking for a solution to do bulk 301 redirects in WordPress. I have looked at some common htaccess redirects but cannot find the right solution for what I need.

**Current URL format:**

```
website.com/year/month/post-name (e.g website.com/2020/02/post-name)
```

**Format I would like to achieve:**

```
website.com/blog/post-name
```

The post slug will always remain the same, it's only the first part of the URL that needs adjusting.

Comment: Can you show anything you actually tried?

Comment: @04FS I haven't tried any of the ones i've seen as they didn't seem to be the right fit.

Comment: You should change permalink structure in wp-admin panel https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/

Comment: @yaroslaww - I don't want to change the permalinks, I am happy with the new format. I am trying to set up 301 redirects

Comment: Something along the lines of: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /blog/$3`?

Comment: @04FS I am sorry, I thought this was a place to help each other. I have looked and couldn't find a solution. Thanks so much for your helpful input.

Comment: _“I thought this was a place to help each other”_ - yes, to help you figure out where you went wrong, when you actually tried something. Right now, your question is basically just “someone make this for me”.

Comment: Well.... @04FS is right... Here you go : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could match the format of the request URI like `year/month/post-name` with regex in RewriteCondition and have a rewrite rule for it if the request URI matches.

**Snippet:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/?\d+\/\d+\/.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^\d+\/\d+\/(.+) http://website.com/blog/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

**Demo:** https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=f2c421fe-e23d-50a9-8988-9a7bac647951

In the above rule, we perform a case insensitive match and grab the `post-name` part in group 1 of regex which is `(.+)`. Now, we add that in our redirection URL with a `$1` where the `1` is the group number(as group number 0 is the entire regex itself).

**Update:**

You can add a `R` redirection signal with status code of `302` [if this is a temporary redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302), or a [permanent redirect `301`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301) (which will updated in SEO crawl engines as well).

To do so, you can change the rewrite rule from

```
RewriteRule ^\d+\/\d+\/(.+) http://website.com/blog/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^\d+\/\d+\/(.+) http://website.com/blog/$1 [R=302,NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: vivek_23 you are amazing! This is spot on and just what I was looking for. Thank you for being so helpful :)

Comment: @CharlyAnderson Glad to help :) Just make sure this doesn't tamper with other rules and the rest of the routing in your wordpress website works fine along with this redirection.

Comment: it works perfectly and fixes hundreds of links so thank you!